# $R$-algebra criterion

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am reading and doing some exercises in Aluffi's book on Algebra and I am getting kind of confused on how to show something is an $R$-algebra.

Based on the definition: Let $R$ be a commutative ring. An R-algebra is a ring homomorphism $\alpha\colon R \to S$ such that $\alpha(R)$ is contained within the center of $S$

But using abuse of language tells that $R$-algebra is the $R$-module $S$ with compatible ring structure or a ring $S$ with compatible with $R$-module structure.

I don't know whether or not I should define the homomorphism that maps to the center or show that the $R$-module has a ring structure and vice versa to prove it.

Comment: How do you prefer to think of an $R$-module: an abelian group $M$ on which $R$ acts (a mapping $R \times M \to M$) by additive maps $r \colon M \to M$ compatible with multiplication (i.e., $r(sm) = (rs)m$) or as an abelian group $M$ together with a ring homomorphism $R \to {\rm End}(M)$?

Comment: I think I prefer to think that $R$-module as an abelian group in which the ring acts on it.

Comment: Then do the same with an $R$-algebra: it is a ring $A$ that is also an $R$-module where multiplication in $A$ is $R$-bilinear: $r(ab) = (ra)b = a(rb)$ is the extra condition on top of the $R$-module conditions. Analogy: abelian groups generalizing to $R$-modules is like rings generalizing to $R$-algebras.

Comment: Thank you and I am just curious what if $R$-module $M$ is viewed as the abelian group with the homomorphism $R \to $End(M)$ $